# ADC input with Low pass RC filter

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, passive-filter, kintex-series-fpga

I’m trying to implement 8 bit ADC in FPGA. FPGA running at 100MHz clock. 
PWM signal is given to RC filter. Knowing that f=1/2piRC, 
I have trouble with choosing the component's value. Is there any rule to 
find RC values and frequency?

I chose 100Mhz frequency, 7Kohm resistor and 10nF capacitor. I didn’t‘t get expected output. I used LVDS buffer of FPGA as comparator. Considering the LVDS behavior, 
How to find resistor value?

Comment: You define the frequency based on whatever rules you need to conform with to the achieve the performance you are aiming for. Nobody but you can determine that frequency.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the response. I would chose Fc= 100khz. Should I chose capacitor first and adjust the resistor?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you choose first the frequency based on the properties you want to achieve, then the capacitor and then the resistor. This is because you have less common values for capacitors and the capacitor will be the deciding form factor (how big it can be). Choosing the resistor lastly is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would chose Fc= 100khz. Should I chose capacitor first and adjust the resistor?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. Something along the lines of 10nF to 100nF. 
EDIT: kHz or MHz?

Comment: I’m trying to track analog signal. I think , I can‘t track more than 10Khz signal. So, I would go for 100KHZ.

Comment: Please update your OP accordingly. At the moment it says 100MHz. Also you want to sample a 10kHz signal? Use a LPF with cutoff frequency of 15kHz and sample at 30kHz or so. No need to sample at 100kHz, minimum is highest frequency times 2.

Comment: Now RC filter is designed for 100MHZ frequency. But I’m not getting expected output. Fpga running at 100Mhz clock, the output of fpga i.e., PWM signal take 256 cycles for one sample. So 2.5 micro second  for 256 cycles and the frequency of it will be 390khz. Now, I need to track analog signal say from 100hz to 10Khz. So I thought to take 100khz cut off frequency. I’m not sure to what frequecy I can track, I guess not more than 10Khz. Better I will take 100khz frequency and design a new RC filter. I will take C=10nF , fc =100khz. How could I know which combination of RC is better?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to achieve. Update the OP with the following: 1. properties of input signal, 2. the frequencies you are interested in to capture. 3. what output do you get now (post the graph) and what you want to change about it plus your schematic

Comment: Let’s focus only on design of RC filter at the moment. In general, I have to track signal for example less than 50 kHz. So I will take cutoff frequency 100khz to 200khz. As you said, I will calculate values of R considering capacitor value from 10nF to 100nF. How would I know which combinations of RC is better for specific frequency? How to find error rate?

Comment: Try a combination, see the results and act accordingly. I can't tell you what the best combination is, as I don't know it myself. I would use a cap in range of tens of nF since it has to be somewhat fast. Also it doesnt have to be precise. A ballpark figure is close enough most of the time. Just pick a frequency, pick a capacitor value that you have on hand or can obtain easily and calculate the corresponding resistor. Test it, and if it looks good, stay with the values.

Comment: Thank you. I will check.

Comment: Also, your signal properties are all over the place. I've read 10kHz, 50kHz, 100kHz, 200kHz and 100MHz. Stop doubting and just pick values and stay with them. It doens't matter all that much as long as you follow the Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem

Comment: he's making a Tracking_ADC.